# Running adsense on a site with an adult ad network too?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I have a social media site that has about 50/50 split of nsfw/sfw pages. Adsense monetizes the sfw pages. Can I run another ad network on the nsfw pages to monetize those pages as well?